# Chrome - File not found

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-chrome

I have an application make it on VB.NET; this application have a couple of buttons that generate an HTML file

```
Dim PathX As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Web.html"
Dim XWriter As New StreamWriter(PathX)
XWriter.Write(WebX)
XWriter.Flush()
XWriter.Close()

Dim sInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(PathX)
Process.Start(sInfo)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
File.Delete(PathX)
```

It runs OK on all Web Browsers on 32 bits Win XP OS but on Win7 32bits doesn't work if the default browser is Chrome, it's say "File not found".

On Win XP, if I have Windows Explorer opened, I can see how the file appear a disappear 3 seconds after; On Win7 I can't see it but it works fine with IE so I assume that the file is being created.

In Chrome the navigation bar the file address is something like

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files/
```

In IE or Firefox

```
file:///C:/Program Files/
```

Now I move the executable to another directory with a single name and works Ok.

Plus, in another machine with the same processor(i5) it works ok even if the executable is in 
    file:///C:/Program Files/

I came from here
[How I can get data after make a POST to an external HTTPS Web Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939046/how-i-can-get-data-after-make-a-post-to-an-external-https-web-page)

Comment: For security reasons, you're best to avoid putting files in 'Program Files'. Vista and better, because of UAC, will likely cause you issues. You're better off using the users temp directory.

Comment: I will take this in to account for the next compilation but I don't understand how UAC is related to this problem/issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to view the file by way of the file associations.  Instead you need to use the executable file of the application and append the name of your html file as an argument.

I don't do much VB any more but I can point you to a good example:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start-vbnet

Scroll down to the example for Microsoft Word .. ignore the ones that precede it.  The Word example shown is using the ms word executable, explicitly.

You'll have to replace it with chrome.exe, wherever it's at on your PC.

Comment: Let see if I understand well, Are you telling me that I should open the local HTML created file opening the Web Browser executable and send the local HTML file path trough the arguments?

Comment: Exactly.  Because right now, you are depending upon file-association in Windows, and that's not working out for Chrome.